# Adding a second custom field

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom field 'ExtraCSS' which brings in custom post css using the following code. (It is brought in from a 'have_posts()' loop)

[image]

html

```
<?php $extraCSS = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'ExtraCSS',true);?><!-- get specific css for post -->

<article>

 <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="img-cell" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $thumbnail_url ?>');" <?php post_class('col-md-12'); ?> >
   <a class="linkage" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"</a>
 </div><!-- /#post -->

 <div class="text-cell">
   <div class="<?php echo $extraCSS?>" >
      <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
      <h3><?php the_category(', '); ?></h3>
   </div>
 </div> 

</article>
```

*EDIT
I want to add 1 more custom field ('BG-align') with either values 'BG-align-L' or 'BG-align-R'. I figured I just add another similar line of code under the current one.

ex.

```
  <?php $extraCSS = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'ExtraCSS',true);?>
  <?php $BGalign = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'BGalign',true);?>
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to *edit:

'BGalign' have to be defined in post (by "Add New Custom Field"), otherwise it is just empty.

You could set default value (edit "default-value") if not set in post:

```
<?php 
$BGalign = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'BGalign',true);
$BGalign = ( !empty($BGalign) ? $BGalign : "default-value" );
?>
```

Then remember to echo that new php variable. For example:

```
<div class="<?php echo $extraCSS . " " . $BGalign; ?>" >
```

`.` is dot joining variables into one string

`" "` is empty space for sure that your both classes names will not be connected

Comment: Sounds like it's close, but I'm not applying $BGalign to the same div as $extraCSS. $BGalign will go on the first div (with class="img-cell) and $extraCSS applies to 'text-cell.'

Comment: I added $BGalign = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'BGalign',true); and then made the first div ... class="img-cell <?php echo $BGalign?>" but it's not working

Comment: Fixed it! prob was on my end, thanks for the help your code helped. I had some extra .'s in my value code